# PrimeFaces commandButton actionListener not firing

Tags: jsf, netbeans, primefaces

I am having trouble getting my `actionListener` in a `<p:commandButton>` to fire inside of a dialog. I've tried changing it to action, removing the `()`, adding the `()`, changing the scope of the managed bean, moving around the ajax statements and nothing has helped so far. Everything worked until I updated Netbeans, everything broke, somehow a library was removed, it was the commons-fileupload jar.

This happened with no changes to the code, only after netbeans updated. Netbeans 7.3, JSF2.2, Tomcat 7, jdk1.7, primefaces 4.0. There is a working version of this inside of my tomcat manager application, if I could possibly retrieve that hopefully everything would be back in working order but I can't find anything about getting the files back from tomcat. So my question is, why is this not firing? Is it the order of my calls in the button? I can't wrap my head around why this is not working.

EDIT Error I recieve after switching form and dialog positions -

```
    Jul 10, 2014 11:50:48 AM     com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
    SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/sampleExport.xhtml]
    javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with expression ":searchDialogID" referenced from "mainForm:j_idt22".
    at   org.primefaces.expression.SearchExpressionFacade.resolveComponentInternal(SearchExpressionFacade.java:271)
```

EDIT 3 Revised
Bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SampleExportController implements Serializable {


//Variables used to show or hide panels on the webpage
private boolean _addTill = false;
private boolean _allowAddingExport;
private boolean _allowDelExport;
private boolean _allowModExport;
private boolean _allowReading;
private boolean _previousCrop;
private boolean _spreadSelected;
//Variables Used For Whole Form
private ArrayList<Account> _agronomers;

private StreamedContent _file;
private ArrayList<String> _growers;
private SampleSearch _search;
private LabSampleHelper _labHelper;
private ArrayList<AdminLabNumber> _labNumbers;
private NutrientsGuide _nutriGuide;
private SampleAdminHelper _saHelper;
private List<String> _sampleTypes;
private SampleAlter _selectedSample;
private AdminLabNumber _selectedLab;
private QueryHelper _qHelper;
private List<String> _years;

public SampleExportController() {
    AllowedRights awdRight = AllowedRights.getAllowedRights();
    Access rights = awdRight.getAccessRigths("exportSample");
    if (rights != null) {
        _allowAddingExport = rights.getOperationAdd();
        _allowDelExport = rights.getOperationDel();
        _allowModExport = rights.getOperationMod();
        _allowReading = rights.getReadAccess();
    } else {
        _allowAddingExport = false;
        _allowDelExport = false;
        _allowModExport = false;
        _allowReading = false;
    }
    _search = new SampleSearch();
    _saHelper = new SampleAdminHelper();
    _qHelper = new QueryHelper();
    _years = _saHelper.getYears();
    if (_years != null && !_years.isEmpty()) {
        _search.setYear(_years.get(0));
    }
    _sampleTypes = _saHelper.getSampleTypes();
    _labHelper = new LabSampleHelper();
}




public void initSearch() {
    AccountHelper acHelper = new AccountHelper();
    _agronomers = acHelper.getAllAgronomers();
    SampleAdminHelper saHelper = new SampleAdminHelper();
    _growers = saHelper.getAllGrowers();
}

public void loadSearch() {
    UIComponent table = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent(":mainForm:DTsamples");
    table.setValueExpression("sortBy", null);
    _search.setStage("Completed");
    _labNumbers = _saHelper.exportSampleSearch(_search);
    ExportFormatHelper efHelper = new ExportFormatHelper();
    for (int i = 0; i < _labNumbers.size(); i++) {
        _labNumbers.get(i).addExportSettings(efHelper.getFormats(_labNumbers.get(i).getAccountNumber(), _labNumbers.get(i).getSampleType()));
    }
    //loadExportSettings from account
    _agronomers.clear();
    _growers.clear();
}



/**
 * @return the _search
 */
public SampleSearch getSearch() {
    return _search;
}

/**
 * @return the _labNumbers
 */
public ArrayList<AdminLabNumber> getLabNumbers() {
    return _labNumbers;
}

/**
 * @return the _agronomers
 */
public ArrayList<Account> getAgronomers() {
    return _agronomers;
}

/**
 * @return the _growers
 */
public ArrayList<String> getGrowers() {
    return _growers;
}

/**
 * @return the _selectedSample
 */
public SampleAlter getSelectedSample() {
    return _selectedSample;
}

/**
 * @param selectedSample the _selectedSample to set
 */
public void setSelectedSample(SampleAlter selectedSample) {
    this._selectedSample = selectedSample;
    //This gets the value of the initial till level from the sample
    _initialTill = _selectedSample.getTilled();
    _initialPreviousCrop = _selectedSample.getPreviousCrop();
    if (selectedSample.getSampleType().equalsIgnoreCase("Soil")) {

        if (_crop1 == null | _crop2 == null || _crop3 == null) {
            _crop1 = new CropGuide(_qHelper, _selectedSample);
            _crop2 = new CropGuide(_qHelper, _selectedSample);

            _crop3 = new CropGuide(_qHelper, _selectedSample);
        }
        _nutriGuide = new NutrientsGuide(_crop1.getRec(),_selectedSample);
        boolean flag1, flag2, flag3;
        flag1 = _crop1.refresh();
        flag2 = _crop2.refresh();
        flag3 = _crop3.refresh();
        if (flag1 || flag2 || flag3) {
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("nutrientguides");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @return the _file
 */
public StreamedContent getFile() {
    return _file;
}


/**
 * @return the _selectedLab
 */
public AdminLabNumber getSelectedLab() {
    return _selectedLab;
}

/**
 * @param selectedLab the _selectedLab to set
 */
public void setSelectedLab(AdminLabNumber selectedLab) {
    this._selectedLab = selectedLab;
}


/**
 * @return the _years
 */
public List<String> getYears() {
    return _years;
}

/**
 * @return the _sampleTypes
 */
public List<String> getSampleTypes() {
    return _sampleTypes;
}


public void setPreviousCrop(boolean _previousCrop) {
    this._previousCrop = _previousCrop;
}

}
```

xhtml mostly full

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="template/desktop_viewer.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="PageName">
            <title>Sample Export</title> 
        </ui:define>

        <ui:define name="PageHeader">
            Sample Export
        </ui:define>

        <ui:define name="PageLocation">
            Viewer
        </ui:define>  

        <ui:define name="Body" >
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function start() {
                    statusDialog.show();
                }

                function stop() {
                    statusDialog.hide();
                }
            </script> 
            <h:form id="mainForm" rendered="#{sampleExportController.allowReading eq true}">
                <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog" header="Status" resizable="false" draggable="false" closable="false" appendToBody="true">
                    <p:graphicImage value="./resources/images/ajaxloading.gif" />
                </p:dialog>

                <p:ajaxStatus style="width:16px;height:16px;" id="ajaxStatusPanel">
                    <f:facet name="start">
                        <h:graphicImage value="./resources/images/ajaxloading.gif" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="complete">
                        <h:outputText value="" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:ajaxStatus>
                <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"/>

                <p:commandButton oncomplete="searchDialog.show()" update=":innerSearch:searchDialogID" value="Search" icon="ui-icon-search" actionListener="#{sampleExportController.initSearch}"/>  
                <p:dataTable id="DTsamples" widgetVar="DTsamplesVw" var="labNumbers" value="#{sampleExportController.labNumbers}" 
                             paginator="true" rows="10" scrollable="true" rowStyleClass="#{labNumbers.rowColorByType}">
                    <p:column style="width:10px">
                        <p:rowToggler />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="LabNumber" footerText="LabNumber">
                        #{labNumbers.number} 
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Sample Type" footerText="Sample Type">
                        #{labNumbers.sampleType} 
                    </p:column>
                    <p:rowExpansion > 
                        <p:panelGrid style="width: 460px;">
                            <f:facet name="header">  
                                <p:row>
                                    <p:column colspan="1" style="width: 320px">
                                        Submitter
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column colspan="1" style="width:150px">
                                        Lab Number Report Export  
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column colspan="1" style="width: 280px">
                                        Lab Number CSV Export 
                                    </p:column>
                                </p:row>
                            </f:facet>  
                            <p:row>
                                <p:column>
                                    <h:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="Ignore" >                                           
                                        <h:outputText value=" #{''.concat(labNumbers.getSamples().get(0).agronomer.accountNumber).concat(' - ').concat(labNumbers.getSamples().get(0).agronomer.lastName ).concat(' , ').concat(labNumbers.getSamples().get(0).agronomer.firstName)}"/>

                                        <h:outputText value=" #{'Email: '.concat(labNumbers.getSamples().get(0).agronomer.primaryEmail)}"/>
                                        <h:outputText value=" #{'Email 2: '.concat(labNumbers.getSamples().get(0).agronomer.email2)}"/>
                                        <h:outputText value=" #{'Email 3: '.concat(labNumbers.getSamples().get(0).agronomer.email3)}"/>
                                    </h:panelGrid>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column style="text-align: center;">

                                    <h:panelGrid styleClass="Ignore">

                                        <p:commandLink ajax="false" id="AlternativeValues" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop)" actionListener="#{sampleExportController.generateAlternativeValueReport(labNumbers,false)}">
                                            <p:fileDownload value ="#{sampleExportController.file}" />
                                        </p:commandLink>

                                        <p:commandLink ajax="false" id="multiPdf" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop)" actionListener="#{sampleExportController.generateMultiSampleReportPDFLab(labNumbers,false)}">  
                                                 <p:fileDownload value="#{sampleExportController.file}" />  
                                            <p:graphicImage value="./resources/images/pdf.png" alt="Download the report by lab Number as a PDF." title="Normal Report"/>  
                                        </p:commandLink> 

                                        <p:commandLink ajax="false" id="multiPdfPage" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop)" actionListener="#{sampleExportController.generateMultiSampleReportPDFLab(labNumbers,true)}" rendered="#{labNumbers.sampleType eq 'Manure'}">  
                                            <p:fileDownload value="#{sampleExportController.file}" />  
                                            <p:graphicImage value="./resources/images/pdf_multi.jpg" alt="Download the report by lab Number as a PDF." title="Sample Per Page Report"/>  
                                        </p:commandLink> 
                                    </h:panelGrid>
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column>
                                    <p:outputLabel for="exportsetting" value="Export Setting:"/>

                                    <p:selectOneMenu id="exportsetting" value="#{labNumbers.selectedExport}" effect="fade" style="width:160px">
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{labNumbers.exportSettings}" var="export" itemLabel="#{export}" itemValue="#{export}" />
                                        <p:ajax update=":mainForm:DTsamples:downloadLink" event="change" listener="#{sampleExportController.setSelectedLab(labNumbers)}"/> 
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                                    <p:commandLink id="downloadLink" ajax="false" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop)"   
                                                   disabled="#{empty labNumbers.selectedExport}" actionListener="#{sampleExportController.generateSpreadSheet()}">                                 
                                        <p:graphicImage value="./resources/images/csv.png" alt="Download the report by lab Number as a CSV."/>  
                                        <p:fileDownload value="#{sampleExportController.file}"/>
                                    </p:commandLink>
                                </p:column>
                            </p:row>
                        </p:panelGrid>

                        <p:dataTable id="nested" var="sampleheader" value="#{labNumbers.samples}" scrollable="true"
                                     rowStyleClass="#{sampleheader.rowColorByType}" scrollHeight="150">
                            <p:column headerText="Container ID">  
                                #{sampleheader.containerID}

                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="Sample ID">  
                                #{sampleheader.sampleID}
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="Field ID">  
                                #{sampleheader.fieldID}
                            </p:column> 
                            <p:column headerText="Grower">  
                                #{sampleheader.grower}
                            </p:column>  
                            <p:column headerText="Sample Type">  
                                #{sampleheader.sampleType}
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="Notes">  
                                #{sampleheader.note}
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="View Sample" style="width:8%">                            
                                <p:commandButton update=":viewerID" oncomplete="viewerDialog.show()" process="@this" styleClass="compress" icon="ui-icon-newwin">  
                                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{sampleheader}" target="#{sampleExportController.selectedSample}" />  
                                </p:commandButton>  
                            </p:column>
                        </p:dataTable>
                    </p:rowExpansion>                       
                </p:dataTable> 
            </h:form>            
            <h:outputText value="Nice Try" rendered="#{sampleExportController.allowReading eq false}"/>
            <h:form id="innerSearch"><p:dialog id="searchDialogID" widgetVar="searchDialog" header="Sample search" resizable="false" draggable="false" showEffect="puff"
                      hideEffect="puff" appendToBody="false" modal="true" rendered="#{sampleExportController.allowReading eq true}">

                    <h:panelGrid columns="4">
                        <h:outputText value="Starting Lab Number:"/>
                        <p:inputText value="#{sampleExportController.search.labnumberStart}" maxlength="20"/>
                        <h:outputText value="Ending Lab Number:"/>
                        <p:inputText value="#{sampleExportController.search.labnumberEnd}" maxlength="20"/>
                        <h:outputText value="Starting Container ID:"/>
                        <p:inputText value="#{sampleExportController.search.containerIDStart}" maxlength="11"/>
                        <h:outputText value="Ending Container ID:"/>
                        <p:inputText value="#{sampleExportController.search.containerIDEnd}" maxlength="11"/>
                        <h:outputText value="Season:"/>
                        <p:selectOneMenu  value="#{sampleExportController.search.year}"  
                                          panelStyle="width:150px" effect="fade" var="p" style="width:160px"  
                                          filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains">  
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />  
                            <f:selectItems value="#{sampleExportController.years}" var="year" itemLabel="#{year}" itemValue="#{year}"/>                              
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <p:outputLabel for="acAg" value="Agronomist -- You may now search by any value"/>
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="acAg" value="#{sampleExportController.search.agronomist}" converter="agronomerSampleExportConverter" 
                                         panelStyle="width:170px" effect="fade" var="p" style="width:160px"  
                                         filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" >  
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />  
                            <f:selectItems value="#{sampleExportController.agronomers}" var="agronomer" itemLabel="#{agronomer.lastName} #{agronomer.company} #{agronomer.firstName} #{agronomer.accountNumber}" itemValue="#{agronomer}"/>  
                            <p:column >
                                Base Ac. #: #{p.account.accountNumber}<br/>
                                Company Name: #{p.company}<br/>First Name:#{p.firstName}<br/><strong>Last Name:#{p.lastName}</strong>
                            </p:column>
                        </p:selectOneMenu> 

                        <h:outputText value="Sample Type:"/>
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="sampleType" value="#{sampleExportController.search.sampleType}" effect="fade" >
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{sampleExportController.sampleTypes}" var="stype" itemLabel="#{stype}" itemValue="#{stype}"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>

                        <p:outputLabel for="acGro" value="Grower"/>
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="acGro" value="#{sampleExportController.search.grower}"  
                                         panelStyle="width:150px" effect="fade" var="p" style="width:160px"  
                                         filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" >  
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />  
                            <f:selectItems value="#{sampleExportController.growers}" var="grower" itemLabel="#{grower}" itemValue="#{grower}"/>

                        </p:selectOneMenu>

                    </h:panelGrid>
                    <p:commandButton update=":mainForm:DTsamplesVw" process="innerSearch" icon="ui-icon-search" value="Search" actionListener="#{sampleExportController.loadSearch}" oncomplete="searchDialog.hide()"/>

            </p:dialog>
            </h:form>
            <p:dialog id="viewerID" widgetVar="viewerDialog" modal="true" dynamic="true" hideEffect="puff" showEffect="puff"  appendToBody="false"
                      maximizable="true" header="Viewing selected samples" rendered="#{sampleExportController.allowReading eq true}">
                <h:form id="innerView">   
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" width="100%">
                        <h:panelGrid>
                            <p:panelGrid >
                                <f:facet name="header">  
                                    <p:row>
                                        <p:column colspan="1" rendered="#{sampleExportController.selectedSample.sampleType eq 'Soil'}">
                                            CSV Single Sample Report 
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column colspan="1" rendered="#{sampleExportController.selectedSample.sampleType eq 'Soil'}">
                                            Single Sample Report Export  
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column colspan="1">
                                            Lab Number Report Export
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:row>
                                </f:facet>  
                                <p:row>
                                    <p:column style="text-align: center;" rendered="#{sampleExportController.selectedSample.sampleType eq 'Soil'}">
                                        <p:commandLink ajax="false" id="cOnecsv" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop)" actionListener="#{sampleExportController.generateSingleSampleReportCSV}" rendered="#{sampleExportController.selectedSample.sampleType eq 'Soil'}">  
                                            <p:fileDownload value="#{sampleExportController.file}" />  
                                            <p:graphicImage value="./resources/images/csv.png" alt="Download the report by sample as a PDF."/>  
                                        </p:commandLink> 
                                        <p:tooltip for="cOnecsv" value="Download the report by sample as a CSV." showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" rendered="#{sampleExportController.selectedSample.sampleType eq 'Soil'}"/> 
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column style="text-align: center;" rendered="#{sampleExportController.selectedSample.sampleType eq 'Soil'}">
                                        <p:commandLink ajax="false" id="cOnePdf" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop)" actionListener="#{sampleExportController.generateSingleSampleReportPDF}" rendered="#{sampleExportController.selectedSample.sampleType eq 'Soil'}">  
                                            <p:fileDownload value="#{sampleExportController.file}" />  
                                            <p:graphicImage value="./resources/images/pdf.png" alt="Download the report by sample as a PDF."/>  
                                        </p:commandLink> 
                                        <p:tooltip for="cOnePdf" value="Download the report by sample as a PDF." showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" rendered="#{sampleExportController.selectedSample.sampleType eq 'Soil'}"/> 
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column style="text-align: center;">
                                        <p:commandLink ajax="false" id="cMultiPdf" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop)" actionListener="#{sampleExportController.generateMultiSampleReportPDF}">  
                                            <p:fileDownload value="#{sampleExportController.file}" />  
                                            <p:graphicImage value="./resources/images/pdf.png" alt="Download the report by lab Number as a PDF."/>  
                                        </p:commandLink> 
                                        <p:tooltip for="cOnePdf" value="Download the report by lab Number as a PDF." showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" /> 
                                    </p:column>
                                </p:row>
                            </p:panelGrid>

+ random ending tags
```

Comment: AFAIK `<h:form>` should wrap `<p:dialog>`, not the other way around. Also, you can just keep the bean as `@ViewScoped`. Just to note: Netbeans update *is not the problem at all*. JSF and basically all Java code are IDE independent.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I tried switching the dialog and form around and now I am getting an error for the page.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The person that created this system has it so if there is an error at all it will go to a generic _There was an error page_ it doesn't give specifics it just says there was an unexpected error.

Comment: Doesn't your IDE log the exception? If so, edit the post and add the stacktrace or exception message.

Comment: For your *new* error: change here: `<p:commandButton oncomplete="searchDialog.show()" update=":searchDialogID" .../>` to `<p:commandButton oncomplete="searchDialog.show()" update=":innerSearch:searchDialogID" .../>` (do it in other places when you called the dialog as well). Make the change and test again.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Ok that works, and now it brings up the records but they are empty, and when I try to re-search for everything the the initSearch function is not run so nothing is loaded into any of the select one menus

Comment: Provide the relevant code for your managed bean to replicate your problem.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I don't know if this helps but I can go into my bean code and type _labnumbers.get(0).getSamples() with no errors because it knows there is something there. But when I try to retype in the datatable #{sampleheader. and try to use intellisence there is nothing there - No suggestions.

Comment: I never trust in intellisense or autocomplete from IDEs. Again: provide the relevant code from your managed bean to replicate the problem.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I'm not sure if this is what you were wanting or not. Literally the only part of the bean that gets everything is in the loadSearch(). So I added in another class function that actually sends the information back. Like I said earlier when this is run _labNumbers has items in it. But the datatable will not display them. Side note the datatable in my second edit is inside of another datatable.

Comment: The relevant code to replicate the problem would be: the Java class and its annotations, the necessary fields, getters and setters and any other method involved to copy, paste it into a new JSF project along with the Facelets code for the view, with the necessary elements to execute it and replicate the issue. If you have an external data source like a database, it can be mocked, so don't worry about providing such classes/data or instead provide guidance to mock/simulate such elements.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I think this should be mimicable with the code now. Thank you so much for your help so far it means a lot!

Comment: Inside your dialog is a `<p:commandButton update=":mainForm:DTsamplesVw" process="innerSearch" icon="ui-icon-search" value="Search" actionListener="#{sampleExportController.loadSearch}" 
oncomplete="searchDialog.hide()"/>`
Shouldn't it be `update=":mainForm:DTsamples"` (id not widgetVar)?

Comment: @rion18 That works! I don't know why it worked before with the widgetvar name and not now, but this has solved it! Thank you both so much!

Comment: @rion18 post an answer.

Comment: Damn that's good spotted @rion18...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem resides in your dialog. There's `p:commandButton` that contains the following:

```
<p:commandButton update=":mainForm:DTsamplesVw" process="innerSearch" 
    icon="ui-icon-search" value="Search" 
    actionListener="#{sampleExportController.loadSearch}" 
    oncomplete="searchDialog.hide()"/>`
```

It should be `update=":mainForm:DTsamples"` since you need to reference the id and not the widgetVar. Have a nice day!