# PrimeFaces actionListener not calling bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to mimic the [PrimeFaces Dialog example](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/df/basic.xhtml). For some reason that I am not able to find, my PrimeFaces button does not seem to call the required managed bean method:

```
            <h:form>
                <p:commandButton value="Open" icon="ui-icon-extlink" actionListener="#{myController.createDialog()}" />
            </h:form>
```

Managed bean:

```
@Named(value = "myController")
@ViewScoped
public class MyController implements Serializable {

    public void createDialog() {
        System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%");
...
```

The print statement is never executed, like if the Listener was not working. When I click the button, no response is given. No backend error, no JS error, nothing. I only see that *some* request is done because I log when a user passes the authorization layer. So something happens but seems to fail silently.

What I have tried:

- Move the button to other places in the page
- Use an id:

  ```
  <p:commandButton id="ex" value="Open" icon="ui-icon-extlink" actionListener="#{myController.createDialog()}" />
  <h:message for="ex" />
  ```
- Remove the `ViewScoped`
- Require a `javax.faces.event.ActionEvent` in the method

  ```
  public void createDialog(ActionEvent event) {
      System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%");
  ```
- Change the method signature

  ```
  action="#{myController.createDialog(5)}"
  ```

  and

  ```
  public void createDialog(int s) {
      System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%");
  ```
- I even tried to create a `WEB-INF/faces-config.xml` (which I would prefer not to, and according to [PrimeFaces documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_2.pdf) I do not need it) with:

  ```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
     <faces-config version="2.2"
            xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 

            http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
  <application>
      <action-listener>org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener</action-listener>
      <navigation-handler>org.primefaces.application.DialogNavigationHandler</navigation-handler>
      <view-handler>org.primefaces.application.DialogViewHandler</view-handler>
  </application>

  <lifecycle>
      <phase-listener>org.primefaces.component.lifecycle.LifecyclePhaseListener</phase-listener>
  </lifecycle>
  ```

Other answers I have checked are: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42076473/actionlistener-method-not-called-from-dialog-commandbutton), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42076473/actionlistener-method-not-called-from-dialog-commandbutton), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24681414/primefaces-commandbutton-actionlistener-not-firing), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848294/primefaces-commandbutton-actionlistener-not-called), [6](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=8311)

---

Apparently the use of `actionListener`s in PrimeFaces [is not as correct as it should be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener/3909382#3909382)... Is there another way to use PrimeFaces components?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I always add an ActionEvent parameter to my ActionListeners... could it be the problem?

Comment: I think this is not necessary in PrimeFaces... Anyway, I tried adding the javax.faces.event.ActionEvent and it doesn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got to see some error:

```
SEVERE - /page.xhtml @159,146 actionListener="#{myController.createDialog()}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'myController' resolved to null
```

The trick to enable the display of error messages was to add the following in `faces-config.xml`:

```
<factory>
    <exception-handler-factory>org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerFactory</exception-handler-factory>
</factory>
```

After checking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30128395/identifying-and-solving-javax-el-propertynotfoundexception-target-unreachable), I realised that my `beans.xml` file had been somehow deleted (??)

Answer (score 0):

This Dialog Framework code works for me:

**index.xhtml**

```
<p:commandButton id="openDialogButton" value="open dialog" action="#{myBean.openDialog('origin')}">
    <!-- dialogReturn event: data could be passed, see page 587 in PF 6.1 manual. -->
    <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" listener="#{myBean.doSthOnDialogReturn}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

**myDialogPage.xhtml**

```
<p:commandButton id="closeButtonDialog" value="close dialog"
   action="#{myBean.closeDialog('false')}"/>

<p:commandButton id="closeButtonDialog2" value="close dialog 2"
    action="#{myBean.closeDialog('true')}"
    ajax="false" validateClient="true"/>
```

Note: Example shows how to pass parameter from dialog. You can also notice, that the first button does just return while the second one does validation at first. I think these things can be useful.

**myBean.java**

```
public void openDialog(String origin) {
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("myDialogPage",
    options, null);
}

public void closeDialog(Boolean param) {
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().closeDialog(param);
}

public void doSthOnDialogReturn(SelectEvent event) {
    if ((Boolean) event.getObject()) { // retrieve param value
        doSth();
    }
}
```

**WEB-INF/faces-config.xml**

```
<application>
    <action-listener>
        org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener
    </action-listener>

    <navigation-handler>
        org.primefaces.application.DialogNavigationHandler
    </navigation-handler>

    <view-handler>
        org.primefaces.application.DialogViewHandler
    </view-handler>
</application>
```

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work for me. My `faces-config.xml` is the same as yours. I placed the `p:commandButton` in your index inside a `h:form`(I have tried outside too) and `myBean.openDialog()` is never called... There must be something else that is needed

Comment: If you used my example, there was a mistake, missing parameter so instead of `myBean.openDialog()` call  `myBean.openDialog('origin')` is correct. Actually, I think you have noticed this...which version of PrimeFaces do you use? I use 6.1.

Comment: I tried with String and with int as parameter (I edited before). It is 6,2, the lastest one.